# Undefined variable on production setup, correct value on development

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, frontend, webpack-dev-server

I have login function:

```
const email = ref('')
const password = ref('')
    async function login() {
      loading.value = true;
      try {
        console.info(this.email)
        const response = await AuthenticationService.loginToApplicantAccount(this.email, this.password);
    }
```

Running VUE application using development mode and `rpm run serve` this code works, but running it in docker with production mode and docker file:

```
# Choose the Image which has Node installed already
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

I see problem with undefined value:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.email')
```

Another strange behaviour is that it is not only related to this value, for example on different component there is issue with this.offer or this.router so it seems that it cannot see variables, I used also i.e. email.value and issue is still there, but not on dev mode.

I need to know what can be the difference, between development mode and production, I have checked different approaches, from Vue documentation, some articles etc. but behaviour is still the same. (working on dev mode, undefined values for docker file prod mode).

EDIT1:
When I have changed dockerfile to use same dev server as in npm run serve command - webpack-dev-server + I have changed this.email to email.value login is working, any idea what is root cause?

EDIT2: Finally fix is related only to not using 'this' keyword, different server has no impact on this (probably I did something wrong when I rebuilding image, when I changed only code, that's why even without 'this' I had the same error, but today I double check with same docker file, but without 'this' syntax and it is working.) Still not know why it is fine on dev mode, but for now issue is solved.

Comment: I'm not actually sure how it works in dev.  If you're using composition API, e.g. using things like `ref`, and `setup()` or `<script setup>` tag, that API syntax does not use the keyword `this` when referencing other variables or functions. It should throw errors in dev... maybe if the component is using some hybrid Options/Composition syntax it's possible, but you should really stick to one syntax.  That may be the source of your problems.

Comment: it looks like that, because, I had to change to email.value and remove 'this' keyword, but moreover I had to change also server so I am quite confused, not sure where to start to really understand the problem

Comment: you should remove `this` keyword everywhere it's not needed because you're using Composition API.  `email.value` is the correct syntax for refs.

Comment: Ok, I remove it. Do you have some idea what is the difference between servers?

Comment: @yoduh please check my EDIT2, and add answer, I will accept it, because it was syntax issue (not visible for dev mode, but as you mentioned, even on dev I should not use 'this'.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.  I've posted the answer like you asked.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [Composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#what-is-composition-api), e.g. using things like `ref`, and `setup()` or `<script setup>` tag, that API syntax does not use the keyword `this` when referencing other variables or functions. It *should* throw errors even in a dev environment, not sure why yours isn't. Regardless, removing `this` and using proper Composition API syntax throughout, e.g. `email.value` should fix the issue.